# xml tag and text not being found using widcard

Tags: python-3.x, xml, elementtree

I have blocks of xml like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<abc:random xmlns:abc="http://www.mywebsite.com" schemaVersion="1.2">
<abc:header>
<abc:number>8</abc:number>
<abc:type>text/xml</abc:type>
</abc:header>
<abc:body>
<abc:d>
<abc:purpose>start</abc:purpose>
</abc:d>
</abc:body>
</abc:random>
```

The blocks of xml are generated by opening the xml file and spliting the string based on a Control Character. For the list of blocks of xml, I want to loop through to retrieve for each block, the node tag (value) and corresponding text, and load these values into a Pandas dataframe. My code is as follows:

```
    for xml_block in list_of_string_blocks:
        tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(xml_block))
        root = tree.getroot()

        #for node in list(root):
        for node in list(tree):
            if node.tag.startswith(".//{*}header"):
                print(node.text)
```

However the if statement never gets executed, which therefore implies the test and wildcard (`.//{*}header`) is not being found - any thoughts as to why not?

Comment: I guess with {*} you're trying to say any namespace (like abc),.  You'll need a different approach, specify that abc is a namespace, and then query //abc:header and specify.  I'm not a python expert, but you'll find example here.  Good luck.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to mix simple string comparison and xpath. The method `startswith()` is just checking to see if the string starts with the literal string `.//{*}header` (which appears to be an xpath attempt) which it does not. Have you looked to see what `node.tag` actually looks like? Maybe take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces and start over.